# Why is shell redirection not outputting to file as expected with strace?

Tags: shell, zsh, io-redirection

I'm trying to redirect the output of strace into a text file like this:

```
strace ls -l ./ > out.txt
```

but the contents of out.txt after the command are the result of ls and not strace.

But if I do this command, it works:

```
echo "hello" > out.txt
```

Why does strace behave differently? How could I go about redirecting the output?

Answer (score 2):

strace outputs on stderr:

From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html

> It intercepts and records the system calls which are
> called by a process and the signals which are received by a
> process.  The name of each system call, its arguments and its
> return value are printed on standard error or to the file
> specified with the -o option.

Currently you're just capturing stdout via your redirection. Use the `2>&1` construct to send stderr to the same destination as stdout